# Get set cross reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js

I'm trying to make a tool that have 3 inputs that all depend on each other; "Earn %", "Earn $" and "Own Price".

By default the "Earn percentage" is "10", so the initial calculation works... and if I only change this one value, the two others will adapt, because there is no circular reference/cross reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/2m971kur/2/

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
        exVAT: 1500,
        retailPrice: 2900,
        earnPercentage: 10
  },
    computed: {
        incVAT() {
            return this.exVAT * 1.25;
        },
        ownPrice() {
            return this.exVAT + (this.exVAT * (this.earnPercentage / 100));
        },
        earnAmount() {
            return this.ownPrice - this.exVAT;
        }
    }
})
```

**But...** 
If I try to make that circular reference/cross reference, my code breaks:
https://jsfiddle.net/xrwykvg5/

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
        exVAT: 1500,
        retailPrice: 2900,
        earnPercentage: 10,
        ownPrice: 0,
        earnAmount: 0
  },
    watch: {
        earnPercentage() {
            this.earnAmount = this.exVAT * (this.earnPercentage / 100);
            this.ownPrice = this.exVAT + this.earnPercentage;
        },
        ownPrice() {
            this.earnAmount = this.ownPrice - this.exVAT;
            this.earnPercentage = 100 / (this.ownPrice / this.exVAT);
        },
        earnAmount() {
            this.ownPrice = this.exVAT + this.earnAmount;
            this.earnPercentage = (this.ownPrice / this.exVAT) * 100;
        }
    }
})
```

How can I get past this?

Example has been made with Vue.js, just to show a quick simple example of my issue. My real code is in Angular 2.

Comment: Make at least one of them a settable computed.

Comment: I don't quite know what you are meaning. Can you be more specific?

Comment: You have two different formulas for each of your variables. Each variable should have one formula. Changes will propagate through the system until they come to equilibrium. I'll give an example, but I'm struggling to figure out what is the actual desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `v-model` on your computed values, they need to have setters. The `set` function should be the `get` function solved for the variable that should be changed (otherwise, what you put in won't be what you get out -- you can see this in Cobaltway's example where small changes in Own Price cause % Earned to jump dramatically -- his approach isn't wrong, it's just that the formulas yield inconsistent results), so for `earnAmount`, since the `get` value is:

```
this.ownPrice - this.exVAT;
```

the `set` function is

```
this.ownPrice = Number(newValue) + this.exVAT
```

(note that you need to convert text to number). Setting up `ownPrice` similarly (and using `v-model.lazy`), you get:

```js
const app3 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    exVAT: 1500,
    retailPrice: 2900,
    earnPercentage: 10
  },
  computed: {
    incVAT: function() {
      return this.exVAT * 1.25;
    },
    earnAmount: {
      get: function() {
        return this.ownPrice - this.exVAT;
      },
      set: function(newValue) {
        this.ownPrice = Number(newValue) + this.exVAT;
      }
    },
    ownPrice: {
      get: function() {
        return this.exVAT + (this.exVAT * (this.earnPercentage / 100));
      },
      set(newValue) {
        this.earnPercentage = 100 * (Number(newValue) - this.exVAT) / this.exVAT;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app div {
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    Inc. VAT:
    <br>{{ incVAT }}
  </div>
  <div>
    Ex. VAT:
    <br>{{ exVAT }}
  </div>
  <div>
    % earned:
    <br>
    <input type="text" v-model.lazy="earnPercentage" />
  </div>
  <div>
    $ earned:
    <br>
    <input type="text" v-model.lazy="earnAmount" />
  </div>
  <div>
    Own price:
    <br>
    <input type="text" v-model.lazy="ownPrice" />
  </div>
  <div>
    Retail:
    <br>{{ retailPrice }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use `Number(newValue)` rather than the obscure, implicit cast with the urnary `+` ?

Comment: Only because I got used to doing it. Using the Number cast is better. Updated.

Comment: Thank you very much. Super clean solution! I ended up using this one, and I like the simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

I'm perfectly confident in Roy J's ability to find a working version with computed properties that will be elegant and concise.

On my side I'm dirty. More precisely, I didn't have any courage to actually understand your logic enough to completely refactor it. So here is my solution, using simply methods:

```js
const app3 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    incVAT: 0,
    exVAT: 1500,
    retailPrice: 2900,
    earnPercentage: 10,
    ownPrice: 0,
    earnAmount: 0
  },
  methods: {
    changeEarnPercentage(earnPercentage) {
      this.earnPercentage = Number(earnPercentage);
      this.earnAmount = this.exVAT * (this.earnPercentage / 100);
      this.ownPrice = this.exVAT + this.earnPercentage;
    },
    changeOwnPrice(ownPrice) {
      this.ownPrice = Number(ownPrice);
      this.earnAmount = this.ownPrice - this.exVAT;
      this.earnPercentage = 100 / (this.ownPrice / this.exVAT);
    },
    changeEarnAmount(earnAmount) {
      this.earnAmount = Number(earnAmount);
      this.ownPrice = this.exVAT + this.earnAmount;
      this.earnPercentage = (this.ownPrice / this.exVAT) * 100;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app div {
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    Inc. VAT: <br>{{ incVAT }}
  </div>
  <div>
    Ex. VAT: <br>{{ exVAT }}
  </div>
  <div>
    % earned: <br>
    <input type="text" :value="earnPercentage" @input="changeEarnPercentage($event.target.value)" />
  </div>
  <div>
    $ earned: <br><input type="text" :value="earnAmount" @input="changeEarnAmount($event.target.value)" />
  </div>
  <div>
    Own price: <br><input type="text" :value="ownPrice" @input="changeOwnPrice($event.target.value)" />
  </div>
  <div>
    Retail: <br>{{ retailPrice }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Does not look so bad finally.

Note that I added some Number() casts because you probably don't want to concatenate them as strings. Aside, I would advise you to use an `<input type="number">` instead.

Comment: Well I will actually refactor it simply using methods.